# Google App Maker - Clickable Image Map

Tags: google-app-maker

I am attempting to create an apartment complex app for my company.

I want to add an image of the overall floorplan for the apartment complex (I added the image to my app).

Now I'd like to add one of the following:
• custom shaped buttons that line up with each Unit in the complex
or
• Setup a clickable image map on the layout image

I humbly thank you in advance for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split your big image into several small images and made different images clickable.
Or you can put big image on fixed layout, and put buttons on fixed positions something like this [image: map demo]
blue circles with icons are buttons.